# unix - find and replace with regex

Tags: regex, unix, replace, find

I'd like to find all files that contains the string " Of ", replacing with " of", except for strings with a hyphen before 'Of' :  "- Of ".

First I had this command :

```
find . -depth -name "* Of *" -exec bash -c 'for f; do base=${f##*/}; mv -- "$f" "${f%/*}/${base// Of / of }"; done' _ {} +
```

But I want to use regex for the "- Of " exclusion.

How can I do that ?

I'm confused with sed regex.

Using

```
find . -regextype sed -regex '.* Of *'
```

it only founds path ending with Of.

Patrick

Comment: Please, does someone have a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this with [`rename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/rename) :

```
$ find . -depth -name "* Of *" -exec rename -n 's|(?<!-)\s+Of|of|' {} +
```

from the `shell` prompt. It's very useful, you can put some [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) code like I does in a substitution.

You can remove the `-n` (dry-run mode switch) when your tests become valids.

I use [negative look behind](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) advanced REGEX

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly do I put rename -n 's|(?<!-)\s+Of|of|' * ?

Comment: In a shell where the directory with *Of* files resides

Comment: Sorry again, you lost me completely. Thanks for trying nonetheless.

Comment: It is not working. I get this : rename: unknown option -- n . And if I remove the -n : rename: not enough arguments

Comment: So you don't have the right rename command, see my explanations in my original POST

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64751/discussion-between-trogne-and-sputnick).